# JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog not stopping current thread

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

As said on my title, my showConfirmDialog never waits for a "Yes" or "No" button press whenever I call it.

Originally I encountered a bug that involved me getting blank `JOptionPanes`, so now I'm using the `invokeLater` method. I'm not too familiar with the concept so I apologize beforehand.

```
public int firstGame()
{

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            yOrN = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                    "Are you ready to play?\n", "Play?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        }
    });
    return yOrN;
    // will return 0 if yes and 1 if no.

}
```

Before using `invokeLater`, it was working fine (except for the blank `JOptionPane`s). Does this method run another thread? Howcome my `showInputDialog` waits for an input and not this one?

Comment: don't understand, its about standard, requirement to wrap JOptionPane into invokeLater,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SwingUtilities.invokeLater` does just that, it places the `Runnable` onto the event queue to be run later, meaning that once you called it, your `return` statement is executed almost immediately after it and some time in the future, the `JOptionPane` will be displayed.

Requests of this type are placed on the event queue and are process by the Event Dispatching Thread

Have a look at [How to pass results from EDT back to a different thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466229/how-to-pass-results-from-edt-back-to-a-different-thread) for a possible solution...

Comment: Thank you for the neat explanation! And crap the solution is way out of the scope of what I learned so far. I'll take a look into it. Thanks again!

Comment: I've being doing this for 14 years and `Future` still scares me :P...neat solution though

Comment: @MadProgrammer  +1 for isEventDispatch... , in other hand talking about sceleton and its notifiers are wrong designed, no idea how to create code example caused by OPs ...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I'm sorry if this is quite the late question but you think I can use invokeLaterAndWait instead? My application only uses `JOptionPane`s and nothing else, as everything else is in the console.

Comment: So long as you're not running within the Event Dispatching Thread, then yes you could do this. You should make a check using `EventQueue.isEventDispatchingThread` before using `invokeAndWait`, it throws an exception if you try and do this in the EDT